# Drop-Shadow on Animated SVG being cut-off in Safari after animation completes

Tags: css, safari, dropshadow

I have an SVG animated checkbox that I want to add a drop shadow to. The drop-shadow works great in all browsers, however, in Safari I'm seeing a weird bug, where the animation works (with the drop-shadow) but once the animation completes, the shadow gets cut off and trimmed at the border of the box. I thought it may be an overflow, margin or padding issue, but none of them seem to fix it. Any suggestions?

Here's the code in question:

```
<svg id="successAnimation" class="animated" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="140" height="140" viewBox="0 0 140 140">
  <path id="successAnimationResult" fill="#D8D8D8" d="M70 120C42.386 120 20 97.614 20 70 20 42.386 42.386 20 70 20 97.614 20 120 42.386 120 70 120 97.614 97.614 120 70 120ZM47.266 66.452 44.734 69.548 68.287 88.819 95.552 55.261 92.448 52.739 67.713 83.181 47.266 66.452Z"></path>
  <circle id="successAnimationCircle" cx="70" cy="70" r="48" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent"></circle>
  <polyline id="successAnimationCheck" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="4" points="46 68 68 86 94 54" fill="transparent"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Here's the complete code with CSS: https://codepen.io/bluestarstudios/pen/GRRBmdL

Answer (score 0):

Try set margin:0 for svg in css

```
svg{
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve it. Please see the codepen for the CSS I'm already using (it includes `margin:0 auto 35px` on the svg. Changing it to `margin: 0` didn't fix the issue).